# Can I remove something from the update list permanently?

Tags: updates, wine, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit, Desktop).

I currently don't want WINE to update, so I always disable it from the update list:
[image]

But is there a way to permanently remove it from this list?
And if so, can I somehow add it back to that list again, if I want to enable Updates for it?

*I don't want to discuss about how important Updates are, I know that.
The reason why I don't want to update it is:
I'm a musician and I'm working with FL Studio. With each Wine Update I have to look if everything still works, and usually thats not the case. I know that I could use FL Studio through Lutris, PlayOnLinux, but I never got all my VSTs to run when using Lutris or POL.
I'm currently creating an album and I don't want to experiment until its finished, cause everything works now flawlessly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to select/deselect packages for updating, and there are several ways to do that. I am listing various methods, adding a command to check which packages are held.
Note that all methods modify the same [Debian Package Manager](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html) database, so what you do with one command would impact what you see with others.

**apt**

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold wine
$ sudo apt-mark unhold wine
$ apt-mark showhold
```

**aptitude**

```
$ sudo aptitude hold wine
$ sudo aptitude unhold wine
```

**dpkg**

(the "finer" `grep` prevents packages whose name includes the substring `hold` being incorrectly listed)

```
$ echo "wine hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ echo "wine install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "\<hold$"
```

**Notes**:

1. If you hold a package, it will still show in the *Software Updater* GUI, but it will be unchecked so you could click on *Install Now* right away.
2. You may check what other wine-related packages to mark.

Comment: I tried it with "sudo apt-mark hold wine" but it still shows up under updates.

Comment: @WombiWombyte - If you hold a package, it will still show in the Software Updater GUI, but it will be unchecked so you could click on Install Now right away. (Added to the answer). I just checked this behaviour.

Comment: @WombiWombyte - Did this not answer your question? Please post feedback, and mark/vote if so deemed.